# Combine two cell 1) if/else or 2) AND

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have two [scenarios](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aWZ36AKc-7iUTPSKnIiUjeF8pqAPWkYpzXNAbojMbC0/edit?usp=sharing).

- If A is empty write B. If B is empty do nothing. If A and B then write A-B
- Only if A and B contain text then write A-B

I can't seem to build the formula the right way. I need help with correct syntax.

Comment: Doesn't `and(cond1; cond2)` work?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: @vonbrand AND won't work in ARRAYFORMULA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your two rules formula logic is:

```
=IF((A1<>"")*(B1<>""); A1&"-"&B1; IF(A1=""; IF(B1="";; B1)))
```

`AND` is that multiplication

Comment: The result says FALSE

Comment: Ah! - I added ;""
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((A2:A<>"")*(B2:B<>""); A2:A&"-"&B2:B; IF(A2:A=""; IF(B2:B="";; B2:B);"")))
But what about 2nd scenario: BOTH conditions must be met?

Comment: I changed B2:B with ""
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((A2:A<>"")*(B2:B<>""); A2:A&"-"&B2:B; IF(A2:A=""; IF(B2:B="";; "");"")))
It works, but is that "valid" solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=arrayformula(if(A11:A="",B11:B,if(B11:B<>"",A11:A & "-" &  B11:B,A11:A)))
```

[image]

Or the second formula:

```
=arrayformula(if(A11:A="",B11:B,if(B11:B<>"",A11:A & "-" &  B11:B,"")))
```

[image: d]

Comment: Thank you. This is a nice solution, and nicely presented too, but i got the job done with the solution provided by @player0.